# What's the difference between 生态环境观 and 生态伦理观？

Tags: meaning

I think that "生态环境观" refers to ecology and that "生态伦理观" refers to environmental ethics. Can anybody confirm this or correct me?

Comment: jukuu: feed 生态伦理观 get 2 example sentences
with "eco-ethics, ecological ethic",feed:生态环境观, get 3 example sentences with 生态环境 "ecology" (no 观)

Comment: I just can't answer this question as a Chinese.

Comment: You are correct, @Tan Soufflet. 生态环境 is talking about the study and 生态伦理 means the ethics of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,  "生态环境观" is more objective, it include ecological and environmental sciences. Whereas "生态伦理观" is "生态环境观" plus ethics. Specifically, "生态伦理观" is a branch of ethics, and is relative to the moral connection between human and nature, the research object is the moral connection between person and person affected by the relationship between human and nature, such as Good, evil, morality and immorality.

Answer (score -2):

They aren't equal, and we won't say these things since it's so strange, and what actually do you mean?
Ecology should be 生態學，while environmental ethics is same as your original answer 生態倫理觀